# Proof of Menger's theorem. Having trouble with notation

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I realize that this is very trivial, but I can't seem to figure out the notation used. I'm sorry for asking such a trivial question. Here's a link ot the book for reference
http://csee.wvu.edu/~zheng/GraphTheoryIII.pdf

I have been reading the Diestel Graph Theory (3rd edition) book and came across this proof of Menger's theorem

[image]

The symbol I don't understand is the one with the arrow pointing to it. I looked at the symbol index, but that was no help. I was hoping that this was commonly used notation, or that someone might be able to deduce what it means. I would really appreciate the help. Thank You.

Comment: maybe set subtraction? "the set Y without the point {ve}"

Comment: Hmm. Could be. I'm having trouble understanding the rpoof in general. Does that first paragraph make sense if that symbol meant set subtraction?

Comment: @The_Questioner: I know the book and the proof. You have to read it *very* slowly - best is you write it down yourself and think about every step. Concerning the symbol: "\" **is** set-subtraction, that is, $Y$ without the edge $v_e$.